# prove likelihood

Tags: statistics

I have the following problem:

The data in the following table relate to the classification of 11 208 physical particles into five types.

```
Type                1   2    3    4    5
Num. of particles   876 1457 2466 2460 3949
```

A possible model for these data is one indexed by a parameter θ, with the following probabilities of types 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, respectively:

$\frac{1}{5}$(1-θ), $\frac{1}{5}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$θ),$\frac{1}{5}$,$\frac{1}{5}$(1+$\frac{1}{2}$),$\frac{1}{5}$(1+θ).

Show that the likelihood of θ for these data is:

L(θ) = $\frac{1}{5}^{11208}$ $(1 − θ)^{876}$ (1 − $\frac{1}{2} θ)^{1457}$ (1 + $\frac{1}{2}θ)^{2460}$ $(1 + θ)^{3949}$

Question:

I'm not interested in the answer for the problem itself, what I would like to know is:

To prove the stated likelihood I must know the kind of distribution (do I?!)

I plotted the data and it doesn't look normal neither uniform. Can I model it as a binomial distribution assuming that each particle has the equal chance to be classified in one of the categories?

if binomial isn't the right distribution, what would be a good guess? Poisson? Geometric?

Answer (score 1):

You have a complete distribution. There are five events, each with a known probability. So you can use:
$$
L(\theta|\mathbf{x})=p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^np(x_i|\theta)\\=\prod_{i=1}^{876}p(x=1|\theta)+\prod_{j=1}^{1457}p(x=2|\theta)+\prod_{k=1}^{2466}p(x=3|\theta)+\prod_{l=1}^{2460}p(x=4|\theta)+\prod_{m=1}^{3949}p(x=5|\theta)\\
=\left[p(x=1|\theta)\right]^{876}+\left[p(x=2|\theta)\right]^{1457}+\left[p(x=3|\theta)\right]^{2466}+\left[p(x=4|\theta)\right]^{2460}+\left[p(x=5|\theta)\right]^{3949}
$$
which is equal to your answer. Remember that the likelihood is the joint probability of the observed vector $\mathbf{x}$. So if you have a vector of outcomes and the probability of each, the likelihood is just the joint probability. You need the distribution, yes, but in your case you have the distribution (remember that a distribution must not be a well-known one).

Also, you might want to read about the multinomial distribution.